# Is "Order" an appropriate name for attribute of photo to determine its position within an album, or is there more adequate noun to name the attribute?

Tags: nouns

Background: I'm designing a (data) model for a photo album. And, I've got stuck on naming attribute determining an ordering of a photo within an album.

Photo has following (technical) attributes:

- AlbumID - identifies an album to which the photo belongs,
- Order - determines own position within the album,
- Name - user friendly name of photo
- Description - user friendly description of photo
- Image - image data for the photo

I'm quite unsure, whether the word **Order** is a correct noun to name the attribute. I've though of words, **number** and **position**, as alternatives, but they doesn't feel to be adequate either.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't answer name requests, especially for coding and business.

Comment: Do items within photo albums actually have an order? Is your photo album linear? Is order important? Maybe consider giving the photo a PhotoID instead.

Comment: Completely off-topic, but such an order or position is not an attribute of a photo at all.  Albums have pages, pages have locations/positions/slots and photos are placed into them.  The position and therefore order is an attribute of the page.  each page “slot” should then point to a photo.  Especially in a virtual album, a photo could appear on multiple pages.  Same argument for AlbumID.

Comment: @green_ideas thank you for explaining close-vote reason. To which SE site should this question go, then? (IMHO: it's relevant/useful for wider audience)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a more specific (and technical) word for such an attribute is [**ordinal**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ordinal):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1** : of a specified order or rank in a series

For instance:

> AlbumID: XYZ
> Ordinal: 5th
> Name: Willow Tree
>
> AlbumID: XYZ
> Ordinal: 16th
> Name: Abandoned Building

Or you could simply use the attribute *Ordinal* and just give a number without the traditional *st*, *nd*, *rd*, *th* and so on suffixes.

Comment: Thank you! Looks to be exactly the word I was looking for. In other glossary `a number such as 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, that shows the position of something in a list of things`. I had encountered only alternative words, which I've mentioned in the question, but they always felt somehow a bit off.

Answer (score 0):

**Sort order** or just **order** seem to be the usual expressions for this, at least in a software context, for instance [here is a Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607998/using-a-sort-order-column-in-a-database-table).

You could try fancier terms like ["collation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation), which refers to the process of sorting something into some order, but it is probably less comprehensible to the casual user, so "order" would be better.

Comment: What about 'sequence'?

Comment: Your own description uses the word 'position' as the assigned spot within the order of the album, "determines own position within the album."